# TypeScript function overloading with Observable<T | T[]>

Tags: typescript

Posting this in the hope someone is smarter than me: is there a way to get rid of the `as Observable<string[]>)` from the example below and use T and T[] on a function overload?

Check out the simplified example:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

class Test<T> {
    test(flag : string) : Observable<T>;
    test(flag : string) : Observable<T[]>;
    test(flag : string) : Observable<T | T[]>
    {
        if (flag === 'foo')
        {
            return new Observable<T>();
        }
        return new Observable<T[]>();
    }
}

const test : Test<string | string[]> = new Test();

test.test('foo');

(test.test('bar') as Observable<string[]>).subscribe(foo => foo.map(bar => bar));
```

Checkout the real-world Angular example:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { OptionWithBodyInterface } from './common.interface';
import { CommonService } from './common.service';
import { MethodType } from './common.type';
import { createUrl } from './helper';

@Injectable()
export class RequestService<T> extends CommonService
{
    public request(method : MethodType, options? : OptionWithBodyInterface) : Observable<T | T[]>
    {
        return this.http.request<T | T[]>(method, createUrl(this.getApiUrl(), this.getEndpoint()),
        {
            ...this.getOptions(),
            ...options
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the type of `flag` supposed to be different for the second overload? As it stands, how is typescript to know which of the two you are using for a given invocation? Both overloads accept one parameter of type `string` so there is no way to distinguish the two.

Comment: Like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-zcctqq?file=index.ts) maybe?  Your two call signatures have identical parameters so the compiler will always resolve to the first one unless you change it; apparently you're using the string literal `"string"` to distinguish, so you should type it that way.  Also, `test` should be a `Test<string>` and not a `Test<string | string[]>` unless you want `string | string[] | (string | string[])[]` involved here, and I doubt you do.  Could you change the example code to `Test<string>` so you're asking one question and not two?

Comment: I think you mean `test(flag : 'string') : Observable<T>;` instead of the line `test(flag : string) : Observable<T>;` and then the rest of your code?

Comment: This flag is just part of the example code... in the real world I have this issue using `request('GET')` from Angular's HttpClient. It can return singleton resources or collections...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the records, I came up with this solution:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { OptionsWithBody } from '../common';
import { CommonService } from '../common';
import { Method } from '../common';
import { createUrl } from '../common';

@Injectable()
export class RequestService<T> extends CommonService
{

    public request<$ = T | T[]>(method : Method, options ?: OptionsWithBody) : Observable<$>
    {
        return this.http.request<$>(method, createUrl(this.getApiUrl(), this.getApiRoute()),
        {
            ...this.getOptions(),
            ...options
        });
    }
}
```